# How to get PHP to connect to TLSv1.2 only site

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to connect using curl in PHP to [Pronto Cycle Share](https://secure.prontocycleshare.com/data/stations.json) (using PHP 5.6.2). This site works in the browser and from command line curl.

According to [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=secure.prontocycleshare.com&s=67.22.239.200), it is only accepting TLS 1.2.

In PHP, using CURL (version 7.28.1) PHP fails to negotiate and gives me `Curl error: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Using file_get_contents, the code:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create([
'ssl' => [
    'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLS_CLIENT
  ],
]);
$html = file_get_contents($url, false, $ctx);
```

Returns:

```
Message:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

`print_r(OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT)` says OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011, so that's fairly old. I'm using MAMP PRO on the Mac.

Is there any way to connect to this server using simple PHP methods?

Answer (score 1):

Your version of cURL doesn't support TLS 1.2, you need to upgrade.

> CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4), CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5) or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6) only work for PHP versions using curl 7.34 or newer.

[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#115993)

Comment: That only references the constants used to define a particular version. [CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 has always been available](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSLVERSION.html), and indicates TLS v 1.x